# Can't import PIL in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I've tried to import PIL.Image, but it doesn't work! Its definitely installed (with pip) and I also restartet my PC. It even shows up in the proposals of VSCode but somehow it doesn't work!

I am using Python 3.11

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import PIL.Image
import io
import base64
import PySimpleGUI as gui
import shutil
import time
import webbrowser
import os
```

Error:

```
  File "c:\Users\#\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.20.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,    
  File "c:\Users\#\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.20.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\#\Documents\GitHub\mcbg_gen\background.py", line 2, in <module>
    import PIL.Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Here's a screenshot of that same information:
[image]

Comment: Did you install PIL or Pillow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the error!** I had multiple Python versions installed, which overlapped each other! Thats ended up being a total mess with installed Library's. So I ended up uninstalling all Python versions I had and then reinstalling only Python 3.11.1 from the Microsoft store, so it updates automatically and then reinstalling all Library's! Thanks for all responses!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from PIL import Image
```

instead of:

```
from pynput.keyboard import PIL.Image
```

PIL is a different library

Comment: That doesn't work either!
the line 
`from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller` 
isn't the same as 
`import PIL.Image`.

I've tried
`from PIL import Image` but that also don't work :/

Comment: You should install PIL library to do that